# How Can I Block Flow Until Request

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I wrote one small application with Swift 2.0 and it downloads single JSON data(at AppDelegate file) from remote server and using that data in several tab views.

My question is i want to create or block flow when application starts until JSON data is downloaded.

What will be best approach ? and how can i done ? Thanks.

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

  var window: UIWindow?

    var data: JSON = []
    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    loadData()

    return true
    }

    func loadData () {
      Alamofire.request(.GET, "...", parameters: nil)
        .responseJSON { response in
          data = JSON(response.result.value!)
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can consider approach take a screenshot of the current screen in main view controller in viewDidLoad till downloading finished. Also, you can put  activity indicator upper the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by "flow". You can prevent user interaction with `UIApplication.sharedApplication.beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()` before the network call happens and re-enable with `endIgnoringInteractionEvents()`, but it would be quite user-hostile to do this without also showing some sort of visual indicator that something was taking place, like an activity indicator.

You'll also want to consider what will happen to your users (or app store reviewers) in no-network conditions. Can you include a default set of data in the app for use as a fallback? Store the last data that was returned?

Comment: Showing of some "Loading indicator" would be great ;)

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is *not* to do what you want to do.

Your app has a certain set of data available to do it. You display that set of data, no matter what it is. Then you start an asynchronous request. When the data arrives, you change the set of data available to your app, and refresh all views.

Answer (score -1):

u can use `Semaphore`

> A dispatch semaphore is an efficient implementation of a traditional counting semaphore. Dispatch semaphores call down to the kernel only when the calling thread needs to be blocked. If the calling semaphore does not need to block, no kernel call is made.

here is code

```
let semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)
 Alamofire.request(.GET, "...", parameters: nil)
    .responseJSON { response in
      data = JSON(response.result.value!)
     dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)
  }
dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
```

**Note**: the Above code block your main thread till it get response. Blocking the main thread is worst case. but some time to fill your requirement you need to use the worst case scenario also if you don't have any option

Comment: If you block the return of didFinishLaunching while waiting for a network request, your application will get killed by the watchdog.

Comment: @jrturton it is work .application will not get Killed

Comment: It will work _sometimes_, but it depends how long the network call takes to return

Comment: If the watchdog didn't kill your app, your customers would want to kill you. This is the worst thing you could possibly do.

Comment: @gnasher i agree what you say. blocking the main thread is worst case. but some time to fill your  requirement  you need to use the worst case scenario also if you don't have any option